# How to detect line break and non-space character in bash case logic?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm writing a bash script and using the case logic to detect if my $message has non-space character, but I also want to detect non-line-break as well. Sometimes my script has the $message variable equal to a line-break and its returning true sometimes.

How do I combine a non-space and non-line-break condition?

> **Like this?** [!\ !\n]

This is what I have so far:

````
  7 case $message in
  8     *[!\ ]*) # contains non-space
  9         messagex='``` '"$message"' ```' ;;
 10     *)       # contains nothing or only spaces
 11         messagex=
 12 esac
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
case $message in
  (*[!' 
 ']*) : contains characters other space and newline
esac
```

Or:

```
case $message in
  (*[!"$(printf '\n ')"]*) : contains characters other space and newline
esac
```

Or using ksh93-style `$'...'` special quotes (not in `sh`):

```
case $message in
  (*[!$' \n']*) : contains characters other space and newline
esac
```

Or you could use the `[:space:]` POSIX character class which matches any whitespace including TAB, SPC, CR, NL...

```
case $message in
  (*[![:space:]]*) : contains non-whitespace characters
esac
```

Comment: mine doesn't have the semi-colon. do I need that after ) :